# Occasional errors using xdotool

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mouse, xdotool

I have been compiling a complex bash script using xdotool, and it has been working very well except once in a while I get an error which is rather annoying, as that section of script is aborted. The error is as so:

```
xdotool: Unknown command: 1
Run 'xdotool help' if you want a command list

xdotool: Unknown command: 1
Run 'xdotool help' if you want a command list
```

This is repeated some 600 times during the script run it is doing, and I can't find the cause. It will throw it up at random at the start of the current call, and the particular script can be called up to 20 times during the complete run, which can take anything up to 8 hours to complete, so you can imagine that I can't always pick it up and correct it!
If I abort and re-start, it works fine, so I'm suspecting a bleed from the previous section or just mis-reading of the $rnd vars for that run. This is a snippit of the script that causes the error:

```
#!/bin/bash
date +"%T"
start_time=$(date +%s)
P=(0.45 0.5 0.56 0.57 0.58 0.59 0.6 0.61 0.62 0.62 0.64 0.65 0.66 0.67 0.68 0.69 0.7 0.71 0.72 0.73 0.74 0.75 0.77 0.8 0.82 0.88 0.9 0.92 0.93 0.94)
Q=(11.1 11.2 11.3 11.4 11.5 11.6 11.7 11.8 11.9 12.0 12.1 12.2 12.3 12.4 12.5 12.6 12.7 12.8 12.9 13.0 13.1 13.2 13.3 13.4 13.5 13.6 13.7 13.8 13.9 14.0)
R=(3.9 4.0 4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5 4.6 4.7 4.8 4.9 5.0 5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4 5.5)
S=(15.5 15.6 15.7 15.8 15.9 16 0 16.1 16.2 16.3 16.4 16.5 16.6 16.7 16.8 16.9 17.0)
#T=(154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168)
#U=(233 236 251 259 273 276 281 284 286 289 295 297 304 315 317 320 323 327 329 331 335)

rnd=${P[RANDOM%31]}
rnd1=${Q[RANDOM%${#Q[@]}]}
rnd2=${R[RANDOM%${#R[@]}]}
rnd3=${S[RANDOM%${#S[@]}]}
sleep $rnd2

xdotool mousemove 746 636 sleep $rnd click 1 sleep $rnd
xdotool mousemove $fac sleep $rnd click 1 sleep $rnd
xdotool mousemove $drop sleep $rnd click 1 sleep $rnd2
xdotool mousemove 744 244 sleep $rnd click 1 sleep $rnd
xdotool mousemove 682 284 sleep $rnd click 1 sleep $rnd
xdotool mousemove 744 244 sleep $rnd click 1 sleep $rnd
xdotool mousemove 881 169 sleep $rnd click 1 sleep $rnd
```

it then repeats the sequence with different coordinates each time over 40 times in each run, and is called by another script that supplies the relevant vars, that are also mouse coordinates and when completed, closes and is called again by the next script of the sequence. FYI, if it errors, once the run completes, it will start the next run perfectly!

I am sure the script could be written in a more logical way, and that there is a better way to work out the rnd function, but this works for the main part and saves me many hours of clicking!

There's the challenge for you gents and ladies! Can this be re-written better and will that avoid this annoying error?

Comment: To debug, have your script echo the commands, so you can see whether variables generate commands that are not in correct syntax for xdotool.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `rnd=${P[RANDOM%31]}` with `rnd=${P[RANDOM%${#P[@]}]}`. Array `P` has only 30 items, actually, and your `rnd` variable receives an empty value sometimes, resulting in `xdotool` calls like this:

```
xdotool mousemove 746 636 sleep click 1 sleep
```

The problem can also be with either `$fac` or `$drop` parameters. One of them may receive an improper value sometimes, like `123 456 1`.

Comment: Thanks for that, knew something was wrong, just wasn't sure what, and that would also account for the number of times the error was thrown up when it faulted out, as $rnd is the most frequently used during the script call. My lack of knowledge was the error! thanks again, hopefully I won't have the problem any more, I'll let you know!

Comment: @MichaelMoore If this answers the question, don't forget to click the checkmark icon to the left to mark this as the accepted solution.